# PHP выводит единицу

Tags: php

```
file_put_contents("posts/$a_i/index.php", "\xEF\xBB\xBF".include'./engine.php');
```

Почему этот файл выводит единицу в созданном файле

> Output : 1

Сам файл:

```
<?php 
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$db = mysql_select_db("mybase");
mysql_set_charset("utf-8");
$sql = "SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM mybase LIKE '$table'"; 

$result = mysql_query($sql); 
$row    = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
$a_i = $row['Auto_increment'];

$title = strip_tags(trim($_POST['title']));
$content = $_POST['content'];
$author = strip_tags(trim($_POST['author']));
$image = strip_tags(trim($_POST['image']));
$date = $_POST['date'];
mkdir("./posts/$a_i");
mysql_query(
    "INSERT INTO posts(title, author, content, date, image)
    VALUES ('$title', '$author', '$content', '$date', '$image' )        
    ");
mysql_close();
$idprogid = $a_i;
file_put_contents("posts/$a_i/index.php", "\xEF\xBB\xBF".include'./engine.php');
?>
```

Файл `engine.php`

```
<?php  
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$db = mysql_select_db("mybase");
mysql_set_charset("utf-8");


$choose = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM posts where id = $idprogid");

mysql_close();


$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($choose)

?>  
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title><?php echo $row['title']; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <blockquote style=" background-color: #eee;">
        <img src="<?php echo $row['image'] ?>" alt="noalt" align="right" border="1" width="100">
        <h1><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h1>
        <p><small><?php echo $row['date']; ?></small></p>
        <p><?php echo $row['content']; ?> <a href="/">На главную</a></p><hr>
    </blockquote>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `"\xEF\xBB\xBF".include'./engine.php'` - с одинарными кавычками всё ок? И что тут делает `include`?

Comment: всмысле с одинарными кавычками всё ок

Comment: Откуда вы вообще такую строку взяли?

Comment: потому что `include'./engine.php' ` который не может участвовать в присвоениях или выводе на прямую.если в этом файле что то возвращается с помощью `return` то присвоить к переменной и потом уже ее используйте

Comment: "\xEF\xBB\xBF" Это кодировка

Comment: Опишите словами, что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: "Получить текст из файла А, добавить несколько символов в начале и положить результат в файл Б" - это вам нужно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кажется мне что у вас срабатывает инклуд в этом месте:

```
"\xEF\xBB\xBF".include'./engine.php'
```

И получается в `file_put_contents` вставляется ответ `true` которые преобразуется в `1`.

Если хотите данные с файла вставить в файл сначала сделайте инклуд и потом переменную что в файле вставляйте в файл.

UPD. Исходя из исходного кода понял что вы пытаетесь на каждый новый пост создавать PHP файл, это не нужно, приведу самый простой пример как это сделать в 1 файле, вместо файла `engine.php` создайте к примеру файл `post.php` и в нём принимайте `$_GET` значение, его подставляйте в ваш запрос и всё, ваш подход не правильный, представьте если вы добавите пароль к базе или поменяете верстку, вам надо будет править все `.php` файлы.

Пример кода приведу на основе вашего кода:

```
<?php  

//Подключение бы вынести в отдельный файл и потом везде вызывать его через include
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$db = mysql_select_db("mybase");
mysql_set_charset("utf-8");

//нужно хоть не много обезопасить себя от XSS
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);

$choose = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts where `id` = \"$id\"");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($choose);
if (empty($row)) {
    echo 'Запись не найдена';
    exit();
}
?>  

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title><?php echo $row['title']; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <blockquote style=" background-color: #eee;">
        <img src="<?php echo $row['image'] ?>" alt="noalt" align="right" border="1" width="100">
        <h1><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h1>
        <p><small><?php echo $row['date']; ?></small></p>
        <p><?php echo $row['content']; ?> <a href="/">На главную</a></p><hr>
    </blockquote>
</body>
</html>
```

Файл `post.php` кладете в корень к примеру и обращаетесь `www.site.ru/post.php?id=1` и получите запись (при условии что ).

Если вы хотите такой url кау вас нужно использовать `ModRewrite` если вы используете `Apache`

Comment: Как это будет примерно выглядеть

Comment: @Duoxx смотря что у вас в файле `engine.php` и что вы хотите записать  в файл

Comment: там новость хранится

Comment: @Duoxx и это ничего не прояснило мне, код покажите что в этом файле, и зачем вообще в 1 php файл добавлять что-то через file_put_contents?

Comment: Мне нужно данные с файла получить

Comment: @Duoxx по логике там должен быть PHP код раз файл php, и если вы его так вставите в другой файл то другой файл не должен отработать, покажите что в этих файлах и что хотите получить в итоге

Comment: Добавил код фйлов

Comment: @Duoxx обновил ответ, думаю суть поймете